# Is there a way to dynamically change the return-type of a function in C++ based on function parameter values?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I am working on a problem that requires me to return different return-types based on my function parameter values that I provide.

I want to do something like this --

In the code below, `doSomething()` is an already existing function (used by a lot of clients) which takes `mode` as a function parameter, and returns `std::list<ReturnType>` already.

Based on the mode value, I had to create another sub-functionality which returns a `shared_future<std::list<ReturnType>>`.

How can I change this code so that it can return one of the two return types based on the mode value?

Note: `ReturnType` is a `template typename` which we are using for the entire class.

Code:

```
    std::shared_future<std::list<ReturnType> > futureValue() {
        return functionReturningSharedFuture();
    }
    
    std::list<ReturnType> listValue() {
        return functionReturningList();
    }
    std::list<ReturnType> doSomething(int mode) {
        if(mode == 1){
            // new functionality that I added
            return futureValue(); // This (obviously) errors out as of now
        }
        else{
            // already there previously
            return listValue();
        }
    }
    
    int main() {
        doSomething(1);
        return 0;
    }
```

How can I change this code so that it can return one of the two return types based on the mode value?

Constraints and Issues:

1. This issue could've been easily solved by function overloading if we provide an extra function parameter (like a `true` value), but that extra argument is not useful, since we are already using `mode`. Also, it isn't considered a good design to add variables which have almost no use.
2. One of the major constraints is that there are clients who are already using this `doSomething()` expect a `std::list<ReturnType>`, and so I cannot return `boost::any` or `std::variant` or anything similar.
3. I tried using `std::enable_if`, but it wasn't working out since we are getting the mode value at runtime.
4. We can't use template metaprogramming since that would change the way our function is being called on the client-side. Something that we can't afford to do.

Thank you.

Comment: Types are fixed at compile-time, while the values of variables are set at run-time. Without polymorphic types it's simply not possible. What is the *actual* and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you think this is the best (or only) solution?

Comment: How about simply create a brand new function, call it `doSomethingEx`, and document the new behavior to the users.  If they want to use it, then fine, if they want to stick with the old way of `doSomething`, nothing gets broken.  Trying to shoehorn features or extra things in existing functions will many times not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done.

You can only have one function with a given signature.  If you have calling code that already expects this to return a `std::list<ReturnType>`, that's it; you're done.

If you could *guarantee* that all existing calling code looks like

```
auto l = obj.doSomething(1);
```

then you could potentially change the return type to something which would *look* like a `std::list` to any calling code.  But if there's *any* calling code that looks like

```
std::list<ReturnType> l = obj.doSomething(1);
```

then that's off the table.

You probably need to rethink your design here.

Comment: "I think it is not possible to have two different return types in a single function using auto"  This is correct -- as I said in the answer, there is only one overload per signature, which in turn means that the return type is determined by the signature -- but as far as I can see not relevant to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you're absolutely right. I have not read carefully enough.

Answer (score 2):

From the example `main`, I see `doSomething(1);`, so maybe at the call site the value of the parameter `mode` is always known at compile-time. In this case, one option is that you make `doSomething` a `template<int mode>` function. I'm thinking about something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

// assuming you cannot change this (actually you have changed it in you example, ...)
std::list<int> doSomething(int mode) {
    std::cout << "already existing function\n";
    return std::list<int>{1,2,3};
}

// then you can put this too
template<int N>
auto doSomething();

template<>
auto doSomething<10>() {
    std::cout << "new function\n";
    return std::vector<int>{1,2,3};
}

int main() {
    auto x = doSomething(3);
    auto y = doSomething<10>();
}
```

Probably another option would be to use a [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) intead of `if` and an `auto`/`decltype(auto)` return type in `doSomething`, but I haven't tried it.